# Postgres hstore for time series

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I am new to postgres and am experimenting with the hstore extension.Looking for some guidance. I need to support basic reporting on timeseries data for various products that we sell. I have a large amount data in the format "Timestamp, Value" for each product. This data is available in a csv fle for each product.

I am thinking of using hstore to store this data in the key value format. Assuming that all the timeseries data for a single product can be stored in a single hstore object. I need to be able to query this data by specific times, say what was the value of a product at a given time? Also need to run simple queries like retrieving the times where the product costed more than $100.
I'm planning to have a table with a product id column and an hstore column. But I am not very clear on how to make this work:

1. The hstore column needs to be loaded from thousands of timestamp,value records that exist in a csv. The hstore should be appended whenever we get a new csv.
2. The table needs to store the productId and corresponding Timeseries data.
   Can you please advise if using hstore would be helpful ? If yes then how can I load data from csv as explained above. Also, if there could be any impact on the performance on inserts/updates in the hstore, as data grows please share your experiences.

Comment: I agree with Edmnud. `hstore` is not a good choice for this job. You can't efficiently use b-tree indexes on temporal values if they're within a hstore. More importantly, updating a hstore will require re-writing the whole hstore in a new row version, which is very expensive compared to just inserting/updating/deleting a single value in a child table. You can't use exclusion constraints to prevent time overlaps if the values are in a hstore. I see no reason to use hstore here and every reason not to.

Answer (score 5):

I do think you should start with a simple, normalised schema first, especially since you are new to PostgreSQL.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE product_data
(
    product TEXT,  -- I'm making an assumption about the types of your columns
    time TIMESTAMP,
    value DOUBLE PRECISION,

    PRIMARY KEY (product, time);
);
```

I would definitely keep `hstore` and similar options in mind, if and when your data becomes large enough that efficiency is more important and simplicity.  But note that all options have an efficiency tradeoff.

Do you know how much data you're going to support?  Number of products, number of distinct timestamps for each product?

What other queries do you want to run?  A query for the times where a single product cost more than $100 would benefit from an index on `(product, value)`, if the product has many distinct timestamps.

**Other options**

`hstore` is most useful if you want to store a table set of arbitrary key-value pairs in a row.  You could use it here, with a row for each product, and each distinct timestamp for that product being a key in the product's table.  The downsides are that keys and values in `hstore` are text, whereas your keys are timestamps, and your values are numbers of some kind.  So there will be a certain reduction in type checking, and a certain increase in type casting cost required.  Another possible downside is that some queries on the `hstore` might not use indexes very efficiently.  The above table can use simple btree indexes for range queries (say you want to pull out the values between two dates for a product).  But hstore indexes are much more limited; you can use a gist or gin index on an hstore column to find all the rows that feature a certain key.

Another option (which I've played with and use experimentally for some of my databases) is arrays.  Basically, each product will have an array of values, and each timestamp maps to an index in the array.  This is easy if the timestamps are perfectly regular.  For example, if all your products had a value every hour for every day, you could use a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE product_data
(
    product TEXT,
    day DATE,
    values DOUBLE PRECISION[], -- An array from 0 to 23.

    PRIMARY KEY (product, day);
);
```

You can construct views and indexes to make querying this table moderate easy.  (I wrote a blog post on this technique at http://ejrh.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/vector-denormalisation-in-postgresql/.)

But my advice is still: start with a simple table, then explore ways to improve efficiency when you know you're going to need them.

Comment: Thanks Edmund & Craig, very useful information. We need to support up to a million products and for each product we need to store up to 10 different attributes over time, for ex: cost,views,number of customers etc. The frequency at which data is collected is variable and defined at the product level. It is not a constant frequency but nevertheless we need to plan for a frequency as low as every 5 mins ~525600 values per product. It looks like there will be issues with read as well as writes when using hstore. We need to support up to a year's worth of reporting. Any ideas? Please advise.